# Uninstalled python2, but still appears in /usr/bin and in file explorer

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-2.7

I am trying to uninstall Python 2. I have attempted to do this both from my computer's Control Panel and from the Ubuntu command line using `sudo apt remove python2`. Both of these actions appear to work, except that when I check in `/usr/bin`, python2 is still there, and using my file explorer I see that python.exe still exists in WindowsApps. Similarly, when I run the `python_version()` in Canopy it tells me it is still using Python 2.7.13. I am not sure what the issue is, and would appreciate any advice. For reference, I am using Windows, 64bit, Ubuntu 20.04.

Output of `type python`:

```
python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)
```

Output of `file /usr/bin/python`:

```
/usr/bin/python2: symbolic link to python2.7
```

Output of `apt list --installed | grep python`

```
libpython2-stdlib/focal,now 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,auto-removable] 
libpython2.7-minimal/focal,now 2.7.18~rc1-2 amd64 [installed,auto-removable] 
libpython2.7-stdlib/focal,now 2.7.18~rc1-2 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
```

Comment: @kulfy yes, I meant '/usr' . However, when I run the lines you suggest I simply get the error -a: command not found.

Comment: @Kulfy 'type python' returns 'python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)'

Comment: @Kulfy the 'file /usr/bin/python' command gives  'usr/bin/python: cannot open `usr/bin/python' (No such file or directory)'

Comment: the apt list command gives WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libpython2-stdlib/focal,now 2.7.17-2ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
libpython2.7-minimal/focal,now 2.7.18~rc1-2 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
libpython2.7-stdlib/focal,now 2.7.18~rc1-2 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
etc.   
Then there are a lot more lines

Comment: ah yes sorry! With the correct / it gives: /usr/bin/python2: symbolic link to python2.7

Comment: @Kulfy Thank you; that seems to have worked. Except that when I open Canopy (python interface) and run the python_version() command it still tells me its running version 2.7.13

Comment: Is Canopy a Windows application? I have converted my comments into an answer. If it helped, you can mark that as accepted using the grey check mark on the left

Answer (score 0):

The output of `file /usr/bin/python` and `apt list --installed | grep python` clearly suggests that Python 2 isn't completely removed. You still have packages that provide Python 2 and its libraries, for example, libpython2.7-stdlib and libpython2.7-minimal. Also, they have been marked for autoremoval since you have no package  that depends on them.

You can remove them using

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

If you want to remove the configuration files as well, use `--purge` option.

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```